# Cannot load jython kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jython-2.7

I downloaded the IJython kernel from github and installed it into the jupyter notebook. It shows under kernels but whenever i try to start a notebook as a Jython kernel , the kernel enters a endless loop.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 version and 5.7.8 version of jupyter notebook. As listed in the tutorial, the path env variable contains my jython install path. 
Running jython and importing java from cmd works just fine.
Should i downgrade the version of the notebook to 4.0 ?
Also i am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
 "argv": ["java",
          "-classpath",
              "/usr/local/lib/jython/jython.jar:/home/user/jupyter-kernels/jupyter-kernel-jsr223/target/jupyter-kernel-jsr223.jar:/home/user/jupyter-kernels/jupyter-kernel-jsr223/lib/json.jar:/home/user/jupyter-kernels/jupyter-kernel-jsr223/lib/jeromq-0.3.6.jar:/home/user/jupyter-kernels/jupyter-kernel-jsr223/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/user/jupyter-kernels/jupyter-kernel-jsr223/target/jupyter-kernel-jsr223.jar",
          "org.jupyterkernel.kernel.Session",
              "-k", "python",
              "-f", "{connection_file}"],
 "display_name": "Jython2.7",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Changing the kernel specs to these ones fixed the issue. Apart from the jython jar the other jars had to be added (jeromq and etc)